# Disable Windows Script Host in Windows

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have to disable the Disable Windows Script Host in Windows with a .bat or a .reg
Purpose is to prevent users from accidentally running malicious scripts.
I could just delete it or rename it, but it might come back after a Windows update.

Comment: What is the context? Is this a standalone computer, or a domain-joined network computer? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 Because I was infected with a bat virus

Comment: In Windows 7 thats more easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in a file "name.reg":

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is a `batch file` or `reg` question:

```bat
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings" /V Enabled /T Reg_DWord /D 0 /F>Nul
```

Comment: @FeZZo, unlike the answer you've currently accepted, which, _in a batch file_, would require to be written to a `.reg` file, then that file would need to be merged using `regedit /s | -s` and done so run as Administrator. Please consider, selecting an answer as accepted, which actually fully answers your question; thank you.